# URL GET parameters to show as a directory

Tags: .htaccess, get

I am attempting to have my GET parameters display in the url as a directory. So, mywebsite/?pix=5 would show as mywebsite/5. There are only numbers I have to look up. I have the following .htaccess code but im just getting a 404 Not Found. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

#don't use .php file extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]

#test get peram to directory
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/$ /index.php?pix=$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost ok. Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ index.php?pix=$1
```

Comment: I suggest keeping trailing slash optional like: `RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?pix=$1 [L,QSA]`